# Using a List<> to store methods in C# Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to store a List of methods inside a `List<dynamic>`to create a part of my Quest system. I've never used Lists and I don't exactly know what the `dynamic`keyword does, so I'm having problems understanding.

To begin with, I've created a test function, and I'm trying to store it inside the `List<dynamic>`, and then output what the Test function returns through the console (`Debug.Log()`). Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Quests : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<dynamic> activeQuests = new List<dynamic>();


    void Start()
    {
        activeQuests.Add(Test());
        Debug.Log(activeQuests[0]);
    }

    public bool Test()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

A red line appears under `Debug.Log(activeQuests[0]);` and the error message shown as below -

> "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be
>   found. Are you missing a reference?"

How do I make this work?

Edit: I'm also looking for a way to add overload methods to each of these functions with parameters.

Comment: Dynamic only defers type checking until runtime, it does not allow you to pass a method in for a parameter. Use `Action` instead.

Comment: Also, you're not adding the method. You're adding its result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the method are always parameter less I suggest to use this:

```
public List<System.Action> activeQuests = new List<System.Action>();

// usage
activeQuests.Add(Test)
```

Maybe a return value is needed. Then you should go with any `Systen.Func<T ...>` delegate.

```
    public List<System.Func<bool>> activeQuests = new List<System.Func<bool>>();

    // usage
    activeQuests.Add(Test)
```

Comment: It'll probably need `Func<bool>`, not `Action`.

Comment: 'Action' apparently doesn't exist, how do I make the error disappear?

Comment: `Action` is within the System namespace.

Comment: Went for Func<bool>, now there's no errors. But `Debug.Log(activeQuests[0])` now returns `System.func 1[System.boolean]` rather than an actual true/false value like I want it to, why is this?

Comment: Use `Debug.Log(activeQuests[0]())`. This is because you store in the list a function that is not evaluated immediately. That is why you need the `()`.

Comment: Uh, that seems like it should have been obvious to me. Thanks a ton, it's working as I want it to now (:

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to not use `dynamic`. If you can make your quest methods conform to the same signature, like `bool Test()` as you have there, then you can store it using strong typing just fine.

`Func<bool>` represents a delegate that takes no parameters and returns a `bool`. So make a `List<Func<bool>>` and you'll have a list of functions that take no parameters and return a `bool`.

A mistake you're making is `activeQuests.Add(Test());`. This calls `Test` then adds the return value to `activeQuests`, but you want to add `Test` itself to `activeQuests`. Get rid of those `()` so you don't call the function.

Edit: If you want to pass parameters to your functions, check out the other versions of `Func<>`. If you add more types, you start adding parameters. For example, `Func<int, bool>` is a delegate that takes one int parameter and returns a bool.

If all your delegates are in a single list, it makes sense to give them all the same signature. This way you can call any of them with strong typing. For example, you could call each function in `activeQuests` like this:

```
foreach (Func<int, bool> questFunction in activeQuests)
{
    questFunction(5);
}
```

Similarly, check out `Action` and `Action<...>`. When you add more generic parameters, you're adding parameters the delegate takes. But `Action` delegates don't have return values, which might fit what you really want better. Everything else works exactly the same.

Comment: I'm hoping to make overload methods for each of these different functions too which WILL have parameters, so Func<> probably won't be a great idea

Comment: I added an edit with some more info. I'm not sure what you mean by overloads--it's possible your real question is something entirely different.

Comment: Overloads, as in, one method with different sets of parameters it can take. Not sure if I'm using the correct word for it, but that's what I meant. For example, at times I will use `Test()` to return a true/false value, but at other times I want to be able to manually set that bool value with `Test(bool value)`

Comment: Hmm, I've gotta question why you're putting all these functions in a list, then. If you can't call each of them the same way, what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

putting `()` parenthesys after a method name *calls* the method, it does not reference the method. 
So with this logic: `activeQuests.Add(Test());` is actually calling `Test()` and looking for a return value to pass into `activeQuests`. Instead, you want to send a *reference* to the `Test()` method into `activeQuests`, so you have to pass it without the parenthesys, i.e. `activeQuests.Add(Test);`. But `activeQuests` needs to be a list of methods (`Action<...>` or `Func<...>`), not a list of `dynamic`.